# How can we set zoom level in selenium/protractor i.e zoom to 90%

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

How can we set zoom level in selenium/protractor zoom page size to 90 percent etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Selenium:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.body.style.zoom='90%';");
```

For Protractor:

```
browser.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom='90%';");
```

Comment: The protractof form works but button are not clickable after setting zoom level ? Any cluse on that ? The error I get is the following :[08:03:56] E/launcher - ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436382 (70eb799287ce4c2208441fc057053a5b07ceabac),platform=Linux 3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: Add import `import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor`

Answer (score 5):

Dont know whether an equivalent is there in protractor (since never worked), but this is how I would zoom-in and out in java webdriver via JavascriptExecutor using:

```
document.body.style.transform='scale(0.9)'
```

where 0.9 is scale percentage. Though for zoom u can also use

```
document.body.style.zoom='90%'
```

but this won't work on firefox and opera.
Hope this could be helpful.

Comment: Interesting option! `browser.executeScript("document.body.style.transform='scale(0.9)';");` should do the trick.

Comment: thanks but zoom would work much better but since its not a standard property so transform. :)

Answer (score 2):

To follow what is suggested for other selenium language bindings at [Selenium webdriver zoom in/out page content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024756/selenium-webdriver-zoom-in-out-page-content), one way to set the zoom level would be to send `CTRL` (`COMMAND` on mac) + `-` combination (to mimic the "zoom level down" action):

```
browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).sendKeys(protractor.Key.SUBTRACT).keyUp(protractor.Key.CONTROL).perform();
```

or on mac:

```
browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.COMMAND).sendKeys(protractor.Key.SUBTRACT).keyUp(protractor.Key.CONTROL).perform();
```

---

Though, I would consider an alternative approach here (not tested).

Open firefox, set the zoom level for a desired site (firefox by default would remember site-specific zoom levels), then open "Troubleshooting information" and locate your firefox profile on disk. Then use the instructions provided at [How to change firefox profile](https://github.com/juliemr/protractor-demo/tree/master/howtos/setFirefoxProfile) to start firefox with a pre-saved profile while running your protractor tests.

Comment: Note that `CONTROL` is pressed down but never released. You need to either do `sendKeys(Keys.NULL)` or `keyUp(protractor.Key.CONTROL)` or just do a chord `protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, protractor.Key.SUBTRACT)`

Comment: Just as a note, I've had some issues with this when sharding tests, as the window must be in focus for this to work.

Comment: This don't work for me with google-chrome for Linux v 56.0 64 Bit on Centos 3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64. Any clues ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways the zoom level can be altered with both **Selenium** and **Java** (one of these approaches is for Chrome and the other is for Firefox):

---

### Chrome

When using [v̲e̲r̲s̲i̲o̲n̲ ̲3̲.̲3̲.̲1](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.3/selenium-java-3.3.1.zip) of the Selenium Java Client Driver and [C̲h̲r̲o̲m̲e̲D̲r̲i̲v̲e̲r̲ ̲2̲.̲2̲8](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.28/), the following works (where the number in single quotes represents the zoom level to use; 1 = 100%, 1.5 = 150%, etc.):

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom = '1.5'");
```

---

### Firefox

The zoom level can be modified with the following:
1. The aforementioned Java Client Driver
2. [G̲e̲c̲k̲o̲D̲r̲i̲v̲e̲r̲ ̲v̲0̲.̲1̲5̲.̲0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.15.0)
3. These classes:
**java.awt.Robot**
**java.awt.event.KeyEvent**

First of all, instantiate the Robot class:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
```

This code causes the zoom level to *decrease*:

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
```

This code causes the zoom level to *increase*:

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS);
```