# Zoom In and Zoom out using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I have a requirement, where I need to perform Zoom In and Zoom out using selenium webdriver. So this is the short cut key that i need to perform. `Control+Shift+Add` Key.

I tried the below code in chrome browser. But unable to perform action.
Could anyone have the right solution?

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.ADD)).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).perform();
```

Chrome Version - 62
Selenium Version - 2.53
OS - Windows 7 and 10

Comment: This answer worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/29100737/14682396

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to do the zoom in chrome (not with the css) you can use the API. For example:

```
driver.get('chrome://settings/')
driver.execute_script('chrome.settingsPrivate.setDefaultZoom(1.5);')
driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/")
```

**EDIT**

In Java:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", /pathTo/chromeDriver);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("chrome://settings/");
driver.executeScript("chrome.settingsPrivate.setDefaultZoom(1.5);");
driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/");
```

Comment: Could you please provide solution in java?

Comment: This is what I was expecting. Thank you :)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: How to use this with background ? when i run in background not working

Answer (score 8):

If you are using headless chrome, you can add `--force-device-scale-factor=1.5` argument to change the zoom level

Comment: This is what i needed, worked like a charm in my raspberry

Comment: for those wondering `options.add_argument("--force-device-scale-factor=0.5")`

Answer (score 3):

You can use javascript to do this action (using css zoom):

For example (in python):

```
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom = '200%'")
```

It works at least with Chrome.

Comment: In our application, the page contents are not fit into the screeen, because of the screen resolution problem. So If i use javascript, the page contents are getting bigger/smaller.They are not adjusting into the screen. So I can't use Javascript here

Comment: And, the application has been built using React.js.