# Zoom in and out chrome browser using selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to change the zoom in Chrome programmatically. I tried using Python to do this

```
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='zoom %'")
```

But this makes it zoom in CSS, not Chrome itself. How can I affect Chrome's zoom?

Comment: That's what zoom actually is, are you talking about resizing Chrome?

Comment: there should be a [driver.set_window_size](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html?highlight=size#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_window_size)

Comment: @Madhan , sorry for my inadequate knowledge, what I actually want is to simulate pressing 'ctrl' and 'add' button to get a 200% zoom.

Comment: Just a thought: wouldn't reducing/increasing the window size have the same effect as chrome's zoom function? It's basically just blowing up / scaling the whole site relative to the window.

Comment: you just want to do that with selenium?

Comment: @DRPK, there is a hamburger menu which appears only after zooming in.I want to check that

Answer (score -3):

The possible solution is:

```
html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("html")
# reduce zoom
html.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.SUBTRACT)
# increment zoom
html.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ADD)
```

Comment: This is working in firefox not in chrome, i want a solution for chrome

Comment: Not working for me in Firefox either

Answer (score -4):

```
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='75%'")
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this is exactly what the OP said was not working for them because it makes it zoom in CSS, not in Chrome itself.