# Selenium & Chrome - send_keys doesn't work

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I would like to sent 'COMMAND' + '+'. I am struggling already with 'COMMAND' + 'a' - nothing happens when i run this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

url = 'https://www.google.com'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)

body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
body.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND, 'a')
time.sleep(3)
driver.quit()
```

Am i doing something wrong or is it simply not possible to send keys with chrome and selenium.webdriver?

What is the right name in python for '+' - is it Keys.ADD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem on Mac OS and Chrome too. There is an open related issue here:

- [simulate key events at highest level in chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=30)

Also see related issues:

- [Keys.ENTER, Keys.TAB, Keys.SPACE are not working on Chrome 44](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1159)
- [sendKeys Command under Mac does not work](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1191)

As a workaround, run the tests involving sending keys to the browser in Firefox.

---

As an [another workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31482860/771848), specifically to `COMMAND` + `+` (zooming in), set the `zoom` style:

```
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom = '150%';")
```