# Starting FIrefoxDriver with 170% zoom level

Tags: c#, selenium, zooming

I need to test my webpage script that handles window width/zoom level. For that I need to run through the whole site in ~170% zoom level.

I know about `SendKeys(Keys.Control + Keys.Add + Keys.Null).Build().Perform();` stuff, but, unfortunately, this solution returns the `NotImplementedException`, whatever that is.

So, in short, what profile settings should I use to start FireFoxDriver on required zoom level? And is there a way to bypass that exception?

Comment: Did you try this approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024756/selenium-webdriver-zoom-in-out-page-content

Comment: Yep, still returns the NotImplementedException...