# zoomed out state object click send keys in java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, xpath

I have a unique requirement where I need to click on an object when the browser is zoomed out to 45%.  Standard obj interaction doesnot work in selenium because the objects cant be viewed well in browser zoomed out state. Here are all things I tried

1. using selenium webdriver - clicking on popup with default button (Confirm) to be clicked so that default sendkeys can be sent

   `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@ng-if='matchClass']")).click();`
2. using selenium webdriver - Sending keys to active element.

   `driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);`
3. using selenium webdriver - Sending keys to active element.

   `driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);`
4. using selenium webdriver - Clicking on confirm button.

   `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='modal-content']//button[contains(text(),'Confirm')]")).click();`
5. using selenium webdriver - click on 'Confirm' button through javascript executor

   `WebElement 'Confirm'= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='modal-content']//button[contains(text(),'Confirm')]"));

   JavascriptExecutor js1 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

   js1.executeScript("arguments[0].doubleClick();", 'Confirm')`
6. Using SendKeys

   `SendKeys (Keys.ENTER)`
7. used robot class to send keys, did not work.

I tried everything I possibly could. I cant zoom in and perform action because that will make other threads looking at other objects on the page fail, thus failing threads. Is there a solution that enables the user to send keyboard inputs without using object references and just sendkeys in java?

Comment: Which `Web Browser` are you using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024756/selenium-webdriver-zoom-in-out-page-content