# ChromeOptions to set browser zoom to 80%

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

I would like to set the default zoom value to 80% when opening the browser for a selenium framework. Something along the lines of below. Is this possible with ChromeOptions.

```
private static ChromeOptions GetChromeOptions()
{
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
    options.AddArgument("Zoom 80%");
    return options;
}
```

Comment: The product I am creating the framework is only slightly too big for the browser resolution we use. I thought it would be easier to have the browser set to 80% zoom so that I can take a screenshot of the whole page easily rather than figuring out how to stitch multiple screenshots together.

Comment: So your underlying issue is you want to take screenshots?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024756/selenium-webdriver-zoom-in-out-page-content -- this question can be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

To to set the zoom level to **`80%`** you can use **`Javascriptexecutor`** with either of the following options :

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.body.style.transform='scale(0.8)';");
```

or

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.body.style.zoom='80%';");
```

> **Note** : Deviating from the standard default zoom value of **`100%`** may impact the functioning of the **`Web Browsers`**