# How to zoom a particular area in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to zoom a particular area in my driver. is there any way to do it?
I need not zoom the total browser.

Comment: How do you do that manually? Relevant HTML, code trials, error (if any)?

Comment: I don't think you can perform that, without a plugin. Probably if you say us your use case, we can find a solution.

Comment: If you want to zoom page content, refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024756/selenium-webdriver-zoom-in-out-page-content

Answer (score 1):

If you want to zoom out a particular WebElement then you can use the below code :

```
/** It will zoom the given WebElement
     * @param driver
     * @param webElement
     * @param zoomPercentage e.g 200, 100, 50 etc
     */
    private static void zoomElement(WebDriver driver, WebElement webElement,int zoomPercentage) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.zoom='" + zoomPercentage + '%' + "' ", webElement);     
    }
```

here is the actual javascript without customization :

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.zoom='300%'", webElement);
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Robot` class:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PLUS);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PLUS);
```

This will simulate `Ctrl + '+'` key press, what is equivalent to zoom in. Also you can get more information in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html).

Comment: He wants to zoom an element, like magnifier. Not zoom the whole page.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Didn't noticed `not` in `I need not zoom the total browser`