# How to get screen coordinates with getBoundingClientRect() in the presence of CSS zoom?

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium

I'm trying to find the bounding box of an HTML element using Javascript in screen coordinates so that I can use external tools (such as `ffmpeg`'s `x11grab` screen recording functionality) to take screenshots/videos of that element by itself.

If there is no CSS zoom present, then I can find the bounding box for element `elem` like this:

```js
let viewportTop = window.screenY + (window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight);
let viewportLeft = window.screenX;

let rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
let width = rect.width;
let height = rect.height;
let left = viewportLeft + rect.left;
let top = viewportTop + rect.top;
```

I can then use these `width, height, left, top` coordinates to record the desired box on the browser window.

However, sometimes I want to increase the zoom of the element to make things easier to see:

```js
elem.style.zoom = "2";
```

Having done this, the bounding box returned by `elem.getBoundingClientRect()` is now scaled down by a factor of `2`. If I use the approach above to calculate my recording bounding box, it no longer lines up with the element.

I've had some success with calling `window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("zoom")`, parsing the zoom number, and using it to correct the bounding box. However, this isn't a perfect solution--what if I want to zoom `document.body` by some amount and also zoom the target element by some amount?

So, I'm wondering if there's a universal way to convert the coordinates from `elem.getBoundingClientRect` to screen coords that works even when CSS zoom is applied to various elements.

- I considered using the browser's own zoom rather than CSS zoom, but I would rather not since I'm using Selenium to set this stuff up and I've seen dire warnings about adjusting the browser zoom with Selenium [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024756/selenium-webdriver-zoom-in-out-page-content).