# how to handle zoom in and out in selenium python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to Know All ways to do that used to zoom in and zoom out?
selenium - chrome driver - python 3

I wish anyone can help me and list all the way (methods) to zoom in or zoom out to try it

I think the press (ctrl) + (+) can do what I want so how to send these two keys at the same time?

i wish anyone can help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024756/selenium-webdriver-zoom-in-out-page-content Has a nice way using + - controls to set the zoom levels on the html element. Other methods include using Robot.

Comment: the link isn't helping

Answer (score 1):

Alternate way would be using **ActionChains**

Its not definitive to 50%, but can be configured how many times we need to press(+/-) to get get desired zoom

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

action = ActionChains(driver)
action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('+').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform() #WindowsOS
action.key_down(Keys.COMMAND).send_keys('+').key_up(Keys.COMMAND).perform() #MacOS
```

Comment: your way doesn't work

Comment: @THEPROGRAMMERNOUR-ELDIN1 Works for me. Let's see what else can work.

Comment: i try it many times and it doesn't work