# How can I get the value of zoom settings with selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I want to get the value of zoom of chrome with selenium and python

[zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxPn0.png)

Comment: Please give more details about why you need this, as I am not sure this is possible. Maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024756/selenium-webdriver-zoom-in-out-page-content?

Comment: Thanks but I don't found this helpful for me I  use python with selenium I want to display the value of zoom chrome which exist in chrome settings