# Unable to Zoom Out of screen using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-java

Am trying to zoom out of my current page as some of the monitors are quite small there our application is not loading properly.

Selenium 3.141.59
Java 1.8

This is my sample code:

```
public class ScreenResolutionCheck {
static WebDriver driver = null;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int width = 1512, height = 982; //Default Macbook Pro Size
    WebDriverManager webDriverManager = WebDriverManager.chromedriver().browserInDocker().enableVnc().linux().dockerScreenResolution(width + "x" + height +"x24").timeout(100);
    driver = webDriverManager.create();
    BaseFunctions.logInfoWithOutScreenShot("VNC Url",webDriverManager.getDockerNoVncUrl().toString());

    driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.COMMAND, Keys.SUBTRACT));
    findElement(By.id("txtUsername")).sendKeys("Admin");
    findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys("admin123");
    findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();

    findElement(By.id("menu_admin_viewAdminModule")).click();

    findElement(By.id("tableWrapper"));
    driver.quit();
    webDriverManager.quit();

}

public static WebElement findElement(By by) {
    WebElement we = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(d -> d.findElement(by));
    return we;
}
}
```

I tried the following:

`driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.COMMAND,Keys.SUBTRACT));`

`driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.COMMAND,Keys.SHIFT,Keys.SUBTRACT));`

`driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.COMMAND,"-"));`

`new Actions(driver).sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"),Keys.chord(Keys.COMMAND,Keys.SUBTRACT)).build().perform();`

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'key':'Meta'}))",we);
js.executeScript("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'key':'+'}))",we);
js.executeScript("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup',{'key':'Meta'}))",we);
js.executeScript("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup',{'key':'+'}))",we);
```

```
options.addArguments("force-device-scale-factor=0.75");
options.addArguments("high-dpi-support=0.75");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Only this one worked but its not optimal as the moment I navigate to next screen, the zoom gets resetted.
`js.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom='80%'");`

I followed all these links but none worked for me. Any help would be much appreciated.
[StackOverflowQuestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024756/selenium-webdriver-zoom-in-out-page-content)

Also Robot class doesn't suit me as I had to run in different OSes.